# -webkit-mobile browser position problem

Tags: jquery, css, ipad, mobile-webkit, mobile-browser

I am looking for a fix to `position:fixed` on ipad/iphone, I am currently trying to the following so that my overlay background fills the entire screen.

```
if(navigator.platform == 'iPad' || navigator.platform == 'iPhone' || navigator.platform == 'iPod')
    {
         alert("ipad");
         $("#overlay").css({
            "position": "static"
         });
    };

    $("#overlay").css({
        "height": $(window).height()+"px"
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The iScroll library would probably really help you.  Although, it is more geared toward fixing the overflow:scroll problem, it also should solve this problem.  It doesn't update with any DOM change, though.  You'll have to code for it to refresh and/or destroy and recreate the iscroll object on any DOM change.

http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4

Also found on that page is this: http://cubiq.org/follow-along-floating-layer

Though I haven't tested it myself, it sounds like it should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, based on [this blog post](http://davidbcalhoun.com/2011/new-mobile-safari-stuff-in-ios5-position-fixed-overflow-scroll-new-input-type-support-web-workers-ecmascript-5), it looks like this issue may also be resolved with the release of iOS 5.